# how the Spring Cloud or Netflix OSS and AWS or Azure clouds fit in together to provide a microservices based solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, saas, spring-cloud-netflix, paas

I have some queries regarding how the Spring Cloud or Netflix OSS and AWS or Azure clouds fit in together to provide a microservices based solution.
How the technology architecture will look like if we want to deploy a spring cloud based microservices solution in AWS using containerization(Docker)and container orchestration (Docker Swamp or Kubernetes).

How does below listed components fits together in AWS or Azure.
- Netflix Ribbon (Load Balancing)
- Netflix Zuul (Routing)
- Netflix Hystrix (Circuit Breaker)
- Netflix Eureka (Service Discovery)
- Spring Cloud security (Authentication & Authorization)

For example, AWS has its own Content Delivery Network (Amazon CloudFront), AWS has it own API gateway which take care of load balancing , Routing and Authentication & Authorization.

Now, if I create microservices using Netflix OSS and Spring Cloud , then how do I put it together in AWS using containerization?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51482499/combination-of-spring-cloud-and-orchestration-tools-like-docker-swarm-and-kubern

Comment: Basically there are overlaps between technologies in this space and you have to make choices.

Answer (score 6):

The netflix stack is built to run self-sufficient without any managed services from a cloud provider. So you could choose between:

1. Renting just a bunch of virtual machines on AWS/Azure and deploying the complete netflix software stack yourself. (Only use AWS as infrastructure provider, IAAS)
2. Using only AWS/Azure managed services and no netflix components (e.g. AWS Load Balancer instead of Ribbon, AWS API Gateway instead of Zuul, AWS Kubernetes for container hosting/ service discovery, AWS Cognito instead of Spring Security, etc). This means you would use AWS as a platform and software service provider in addition to the infrastructure (IAAS plus PAAS, SAAS).
3. Or any combination of the two scenarios. E.g. use AWS for load balancing but deploy some Zuul Gateways on your own EC2 instances in front of your application.

General guideline is - Any platform or software elements of your architecture managed by yourself will be cheaper in baseline costs, but add additional design/development/administration costs. What is the best for you depends on your usage scenario, scalability expectations, resource availability, etc.

It sounds like you could benefit from learning about the differences of IAAS, PAAS, SAAS. See this [link](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/saas-vs-paas-vs-iaas-whats-the-difference-and-how-to-choose/).

Regarding your question:

> Now, if I create microservices using Netflix OSS and Spring Cloud , then how do I put it together in AWS using containerization?

A reasonable approach would be to use AWS Kubernetes (or AWS ECS) as a container hosting infrastructure and then deploy the Netflix and Spring components you still need as containers. In case of both Kubernetes and ECS you already have load balancing, service discovery and more features built in (see this [link](https://kubernetes.io/)). So you will have to carefully look at every Netflix component and decide if it really contains features that you need and are not covered yet by the container platform.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oswin Noetzelmann for providing such a detailed reply.